# How to convert c code fread to vb.net

Tags: c, vb.net

I`m writing the VB.net and need to call API(c language DLL)

My test sample code as follow

```
//Read Source File
char *SourceFilePath = "C:\\Docs\\Scandi\\attach\\verifyTest\\center.xml";
FILE *sourcefile= fopen(SourceFilePath, "rb");
if (!sourcefile)
{
    printf("Error=%s\n", *SourceFilePath);
    return;
}

fseek(sourcefile,0,SEEK_END);
long src_ch_len  = ftell(sourcefile);
rewind(sourcefile);
unsigned char *src_ch =(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*src_ch_len); 
result = fread(src_ch,1,src_ch_len,sourcefile);
if(result!=src_ch_len)
{ 
    printf("Reading Error=%s\n", *sourcefile);
    return; 
}

fclose(sourcefile);

//Read Data File
//Skip...

rc = BasicVerify(algorithm, data, dataLen, key, signature, signatureLen);
```

API Function definition

```
unsigned long verify(unsigned long algorithm, unsigned char *data, int dataLen,unsigned char *signature, int signatureLen, char *cerFile)
```

How to convert fopen(SourceFilePath, "rb") and fread(src_ch,1,src_ch_len,sourcefile) to VB.NET

Thanks

Comment: [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) , [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analogue to `fopen` using the modes `"rb"` in VB .NET appears to be [the `FileStream` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) using the [`FileAccess.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) mode. From there you can use the [`FileStream.Read` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) as an analogue for `fread`. For example:

```
dim sourceFile as FileStream
sourceFile = new FileStream("C:\\Docs\\Scandi\\attach\\verifyTest\\center.xml", FileAccess.Read)

dim result as Integer
result = sourceFile.Read(array, 0, array.Length)
```

However, it seems from the `fseek` followed by `ftell` in your C code, you want to read the entire file into memory. This is often frowned upon since a file could be many gigabytes in size. If you really want to do that, use the [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, for example:

```
dim src_ch as Byte()
src_ch = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Docs\\Scandi\\attach\\verifyTest\\center.xml")
```